# Boost (1.50.0) Thread Library Linking with MinGW

Tags: c++, boost, linker, mingw

I'm trying to link the thread library of boost 1.50.0 and am having some problems. The problem is that the implementation of the thread cannot be found.

I've checked around here, on random sites and on the official manuals and concluded that there can only be one reason for this (since the actual library I'm linking contains the correct files). **There is no auto-linking in MinGW**. This means there can be no platform implementation for the threads available (and hence the error).

One of the errors I'm getting is:

*undefined reference to `*imp*__ZN5boost6thread4joinEv'*

that comes from **myTread.join()**.

So my questions is, what is the library (or libraries) I need to link in addition to the boost thread library (in this case named *libboost_thread-mgw46-mt-1_50.a*)?

And furthermore, is there any documentation for all library dependencies in boost?

I could of course be completely wrong, so any help appreciated!

Currenty I'm linking only boosts libraries; threads, chrono and system.

**EDIT**

To clarify, I'm linking with the following command:

*g++ -LPATH_TO_BOOST\lib -o test-boost-thread.exe src\test-boost-thread.o -lboost_thread-mgw46-mt-1_50 -lboost_chrono-mgw46-mt-1_50 -lboost_system-mgw46-mt-1_50*

I've tried changing positions of the libraries, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, given the file name that you posted, the linker line would be `-lboost_thread-mgw46-mt-1_50` (remove `lib` and `.a`/`.so`/`.lib`). There might be (or you might want to create) a symlink that points to it like `libboost_thread.a -> libboost_thread-mgw46-mt-1_50.a`, in which case you can use the shorter `-lboost_thread`.

Comment: As I posted in my question, the library is boost_thread-mgw46-mt-1_50. But that doesn't containt the platform implementation of the threads does it?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, seems like I completely forgot about the BOOST_THREAD_USE_LIB flag. Setting this made it work.

Strange error though.